# PowerShell MySQL Dump Script does not dump correctly

Tags: mysql, powershell, scripting, backup

```
$d= Get-Date
$dString = $d.Year.ToString() + "-" + $d.Month.ToString() + "-" + $d.Day.ToString() + "_" + $d.Hour.ToString() + "-" + $d.Minute.ToString() + "-" + $d.Minute.ToString()
$backupFilePath = "C:\wamp\backupFileName_" + $dString + ".sql"
$cmd = "& 'C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\bin\mysqldump.exe' -u ipbform -p123123 wiki > " + $backupFilePath
Write-Host $cmd
invoke-expression $cmd | out-null
```

When I look at the MySQL dump file I get this:

`ÿþ-`(bunch of random symbols like its a compiled file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ÿþ` is the [Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) of a file encoded in little-endian Unicode format. Try this:

```
$cmd = "& 'C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\bin\mysqldump.exe' -u ipbform -p123123 wiki"
Write-Host $cmd
Invoke-Expression $cmd | Out-File $backupFilePath -Encoding ASCII
```